# How to instantiate a functor in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

If I have the following functor, how can I instantiate it with a `ListMapFn`?

```
functor G(M: ORD_MAP where type Key.ord_key = string) :
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
structure S = G(ListMapFn(type ord_key = string; val compare = String.compare))
```

or, if you prefer to name the `ListMap` instance:

```
structure ListMap = ListMapFn(type ord_key = string; val compare = String.compare)
structure S = G(ListMap)
```

Comment: I think you have been working a bit to much with MLton? atleast I haven't seen SML/NJ use `t` as the type variable :) In this case it ought to be `type ord_key = string`.

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg: OCaml and others, rather, but you are right. :) Fixed.

Comment: its actually pretty sad that SML/NJ haven't adopted this convention/style, it is useful in so many ways. Some of the stuff the MLton guys create using this really amazed me sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Just to elaborate a bit on the syntax of functors, here are some examples.

First some preliminary declarations so we have something to work with.

```
signature FOO =
sig
  val foo : unit -> unit
end


structure FooUnit : FOO =
struct
  fun foo () = ()
end


structure FooPrint : FOO =
struct
  fun foo () = print "Foo\n"
end
```

Now. when we create functors, which only take one structure as argument, it is optionally if we wan't to write `functor FooFn (f : FOO)` or `functor FooFn (structure f : FOO)`. Actually this applies only when the functor takes one structure as an argument:

```
(* Optionally to write "structure f : FOO" as there is only one argument *)
functor FooFn (f : FOO) = struct
  val foo = f.foo
end
```

However when the functor takes two or more arguments, it is mandatory to use the keyword structure. Note that a functor may take other arguments as well, for example an integer value.

```
(* Note there is no delimiter, just a space and the structure keyword *)
functor FooFooFn (structure f1 : FOO
                  structure f2 : FOO) =
struct
  val foo1 = f1.foo
  val foo2 = f2.foo
end
```

We also have a few options when applying the functor, and getting the resulting structure back. The first one is straight forward.

```
structure f1 = FooFn (FooUnit)
```

However this one is a bit of a "special case", as we define it "inlined", omitting the `struct` and `end` part

```
structure f2 = FooFn (fun foo () = print "Inlined\n")
```

or we can be a bit more verbose, and include the `struct` and `end` part. However both of these only work, because the functor takes one argument

```
structure f2_1 = FooFn (struct fun foo () = print "Inlined\n" end)
```

The syntax is somewhat the same when the functor takes multiple arguments

```
(* Again note there is no delimiter, so we can have it on the same line *)
structure f3 = FooFooFn (structure f1 = FooUnit structure f2 = FooPrint)
```

it somewhat resembles records, as the order doesn't matter

```
(* And we can even switch the order *)
structure f4 = FooFooFn (structure f2 = FooUnit
                         structure f1 = FooPrint)
```